# which database to use oracle, SQLServer2000 or MySQl

Tags: java, database

I am new to java, and also reading the JDBC stuff, I have the executable(installer) for three of the databases, Oracle 10G, MSSql-2000, MySQL.

I wanted to ask which one of these databases should i use for learning and the reason why to that one and not the other one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to answer this question with the information provided.
Depends on what you plan to do in the future.
All three are ok for learning.  Oracle is the most heavy weight.  MySQL is best for very simple things.  MS SQL is probably easier to deal with than Oracle and is a more of a real production/industrial DB than MySQL, but MS SQL 2000 is kind of outdated.
You might also want to consider PostgreSQL which is free like MySQL (or rather even freer)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do expensive enterprise work, then learn Oracle. If you want to work on non-enterprise systems, then MySQL is fine.

Comment: If it were a newer version Of SQL Server, I'd say go for that one but as it is, 2000 would be my last choice as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend SQL Server due a number of facts:

- Convenient tools that come out-of-the-box
- Large community with a lot of experts and materials (ranging from 'beginner' to 'expert' level)
- It's simple to start with - new versions tend to simplify solving simple tasks and only reveal complexity with considerable growth of your requirements (size of the DB and load)